# popupanel, method to destroy it, not hide it

Tags: gwt, popuppanel

I have a question about popupapnel with GWT. The method hide() only "hides" the popupanel ? I want to definitively destroy my popuppanel, allowing reseting all allocated resources to it. But if the method hide() only hides it, it don't arrange me. So is there a method to destroy a popuppanel et reset all resources allocated to it ?

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [removeFromParent()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#removeFromParent%28%29) method.

And if you want reset some resources you can also override [onDetach()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#onDetach%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a .remove() method?

Answer (score 0):

`hide()`ing a `PopupPanel`, unlike for other widgets, detaches it from the document, allowing it to be garbage-collected. It's then only up to you to remove all references to it so it can effectively be garbage-collected (`null` your variables, etc.)